# To add the elements in each(3) arrays and if the sum is not equal ,delete the the last element from the array which has Highest sum

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have three arrays, I will add all the elements in it. If the sum of the elements in all the three arrays are equal i.e s1=s2=s3 , then condition is satisfied . else we need to delete the last value from the array which has the highest sum and then again sum all three arrays to check if all the sums of the arrays are equal. This process should be repeated till the condition gets satisfied . Kindly help me with this. my java code is :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n1, n2 , n3, i;
    int count=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    n1=s.nextInt();
    n2=s.nextInt();
    n3=s.nextInt();
    int[] arr1=new int[n1];
    int[] arr2=new int[n2];
    int[] arr3=new int[n3];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++) 
        arr1[i]=s.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++) 
        arr2[i]=s.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n3;i++) 
        arr3[i]=s.nextInt();
    int sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        sum1+=arr1[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++) {
        sum2+=arr2[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n3;i++) {
        sum3+=arr3[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if(sum1==sum2&&sum2==sum3) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        if(sum1>sum2&&sum1>sum3) {
            arr1[n1-1]=0;
            n1--;
        }
        if(sum2>sum1&&sum2>sum3) {
            arr2[n2-1]=0;
            n2--;
        }
        if(sum3>sum1&&sum3>sum2) {
            arr3[n3-1]=0;
            n3--;
        }

    }

}
}
    if(count>0)
        System.out.println("Condtion Satisfied");
}
}
```

Comment: i thought it was pretty clear, he wants to change and compare the arrays until the condition is met

Comment: yes, I want to check the sum repeatedly till the condtion is met

Comment: Does your code not work? Add an error-case. Try debugging and come back with a specific question if you cannot fix the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this logic i have not good compiler right now but try if you are facing problem comment down

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n1, n2 , n3, i;
    int count=0;
    int sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    n1=s.nextInt();
    n2=s.nextInt();
    n3=s.nextInt();

    int[] arr1=new int[n1];
    int[] arr2=new int[n2];
    int[] arr3=new int[n3];

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++) 
        arr1[i]=s.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++) 
        arr2[i]=s.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n3;i++) 
        arr3[i]=s.nextInt();

    while(count==0){    

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        sum1+=arr1[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++) {
        sum2+=arr2[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n3;i++) {
        sum3+=arr3[i];
    }

    if(sum1==sum2&&sum2==sum3) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        if(sum1>sum2&&sum1>sum3) {
            arr1[n1-1]=0;
        }
        if(sum2>sum1&&sum2>sum3) {
            arr2[n2-1]=0;
        }
        if(sum3>sum1&&sum3>sum2) {
            arr3[n3-1]=0;
        }

    }
}
    if(count>0){
        System.out.println("Condtion Satisfied");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Working , thanks for the simple implementation too :)

Comment: Welcome @StonecoldCold :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this what you are looking for, this method will return true, if you pass your three arrays to it, if the condition as specified is met (Sum of elements in the arrays are equal, if not remove last element from largest and recheck for the condition).

```
public class SumArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Cant converge
        int[] arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] arr2={6,7,8,9};
        int[] arr3={10,11,12,13};
        new SumArray().sumBasedArrayResize(arr1, arr2, arr3);

        //Converge
        int[] arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] arr2={1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] arr3={1,2,3,4,5};
        new SumArray().sumBasedArrayResize(arr1, arr2, arr3);

    }

    private boolean sumBasedArrayResize(int[] arr1, int[] arr2,int[] arr3) {
        while(true) {
            int sum1 = IntStream.of(arr1).sum();
            int sum2 = IntStream.of(arr2).sum();
            int sum3 = IntStream.of(arr3).sum();
            if (sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3) {
                // ok case
                System.out.println("Sum of arr1 == Sum of arr2 == Sum of arr3");
                return true;
            } else if (arr1.length == 0 || arr2.length == 0 || arr3.length == 0 ) {
                System.out.println(" Cant converge ");
                return false;
            }
            if (sum1 > sum2) {
                if (sum1 > sum3) {
                    //sum1 is large
                    System.out.println("Sum of elements in arr1 is  largest, removing last element from arr1 " + sum1);
                    arr1 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length - 1);
                } else {
                    // sum3 large
                    System.out.println("Sum of elements in arr3 is  largest, removing last element from arr3 " + + sum3);
                    arr3 = Arrays.copyOf(arr3, arr3.length - 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (sum2 > sum3) {
                    //sum2 is large
                    System.out.println("Sum of elements in arr2 is  largest, removing last element from arr2 " +  sum2);
                    arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr2, arr2.length - 1);
                } else {
                    // sum3 large
                    System.out.println("Sum of elements in arr3 is  largest, removing last element from arr3 " + + sum3);
                    arr3 = Arrays.copyOf(arr3, arr3.length - 1);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        //sample arrays
        int[] arr1 = {10,20,30};
        int[] arr2 = {20,10,50};
        int[] arr3 = {15,15,10};

        //arrays last index
        int arr1LastIndex = arr1.length - 1;
        int arr2LastIndex = arr2.length - 1;;
        int arr3LastIndex = arr3.length - 1;;

        boolean whileCondition = false;
        boolean result = false;

        while(!whileCondition){

            int sum1 = 0;
            int sum2 = 0;
            int sum3 = 0;

            for(int num : arr1){
                sum1 += num;
            }

            for(int num : arr2){
                sum2 += num;
            }

            for(int num : arr3){
                sum3 += num;
            }

            //check which array sum is largest and make it's last element equal to 0
            if(sum1 > sum2 && sum1 > sum3){
                arr1[arr1LastIndex] = 0;
                arr1LastIndex -= 1;
            }else if(sum2 > sum1 && sum2 > sum3){
                arr2[arr2LastIndex] = 0;
                arr2LastIndex -= 1;
            }else{
                arr3[arr3LastIndex] = 0;
                arr3LastIndex -= 1;
            }

            //checks if all sums are equal
            if(sum1 == sum2 && sum2 == sum3){
                whileCondition = true;
                result = true;
            }

            //checks if the sums we're never equal after going through the whole array
            if(arr1LastIndex < 0 || arr1LastIndex < 0 || arr3LastIndex < 0){
                whileCondition = true;
                result = false;
            }
        }

        if (result){
            System.out.println("Condition was met!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Condition was NEVER met!");
        }
    }
```